# Editing unity scene files post-compile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a mod engine for a unity game. It is 2D based and stores all the level data in separate files ("level1", "level2") in the game data folder (I believe this is standard for unity). I am looking to be able to edit these in post to add/remove game objects in the scene. I wish to be able  to do this programmatically in C#.

I've already had a look at the file in the hex editor, and it seems like this is possible (I can see basic game object data).

Currently im loading the scene then moving all objects around or instantiating new ones, but this is proving to be unstable because of the way the game handles objects.

If anyone could point me in the direction of how i would go about this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Update for those that are asking for additional info: Yes, by levels I mean scenes, unity saves them as “level0”, “level1”, etc

I am not the author of the game, the game was not designed with changing the scenes in mind, almost all of the interacatble objects have special riggers crafted to them, so in order to move them it requires me to be extremely careful or the game crashes.

Comment: Are the levels unity scenes? Or a custom file format?

Comment: Also, please edit your answer and explain why you can't modify the scene once it's loaded? Why is it unstable? Because that seems like the real problem.

Comment: The compiled scene files aren't designed to be edited, and the file structure isn't known or published. If you want to move things in your scene, you need to do it during runtime through code. That's the correct way to do it. I don't know what you mean by "proving to be unstable because of the way the game handles objects", but if your game is breaking from moving objects, then that's something you probably need to fix. Consider making a new question regarding the instability when moving objects.

Comment: Added info you asked for to the post.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write it seems your separate files are actual Unity3D scenes. You should only have once scene and a system in place that reads and loads your data, for example from text files, then programmatically instantiate those object at run time.

Comment: Forgot to mention in my post, but the game isn’t mine, I am writing a mod engine for a pre existing game